# Blank pages with Memoir class, titlesec, hyperref

Tags: page-breaking

I have many long threeparttables and frequently blank pages are being thrown between them.  This seems to be some interaction between titlesec and hyperref - if I comment either of them out in the MWE, there are no blank pages but, as is, there's a blank page 3.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Update: It's related to the

```
\subsection{Continuations après réponse montrant au moins M 4e}
```

and the threeparttable that follows it.  If I copy and paste those they always seem to throw a blank page before them.  Taking even one line out of that table seems to eliminate the blank page.  Might this be a float issue?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, 11pt, oneside, onecolumn]{memoir}%                                                                      
\RequirePackage[para]{threeparttable}%                                          
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}%                                            
\RequirePackage{hyperref}%                                                      

\begin{document}                                                                
\chapter{A new chapter}                                                         

\section{Conditions d'utilisation}                                              
Avec xxx{20}{21} HL, main régulière, mais aussi :                               
\begin{enumerate}                                                               
\item xxx{19}{20} H et mineure xxx{5} ;                                         
\item xxx{18}{19} H mineure xxx{6} ;                                            
\item xxx{19}{20} H et majeure xxx{5} (idéalement autre majeure xxx{3}), (5422) possible (doubletons gardés), voire 44(41) avec honneur sec.                    
\end{enumerate}       

\section{Réponses et développements}                                            
A noter : Le répondant peut faire un Stayman avec un (4333), puisque l’ouvreur  est moins souvent miroir.                                                       

\smallskip                                                                      
\begin{threeparttable}[t]                                                       
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}}                                                        
\toprule                                                                        
2xxx    &                   &\\                                                 
        &3xxx               &Stayman xxx{4}{+} H ;\\                            
        &xxx{3xxx}{4xxx}    &Texas xxx{4}{+} H ou M xxx{6}{+} ;\\               
        &3xxx               &xxx{4}{11} H ;\\                                   
        &4xxx               &xxx{Bicolore majeur 5--5} ;\\                      
        &4xxx               &xxx{Bicolore majeur au moins 5--6} ;\\             
        &4xxx(xxx)          &xxx{Bicolore mineur au moins 5--4, court à  xxx(xxx)} ;\\                                                                   
        &4xxx               &Quantitatif ;\\                                    
        &5xxx               &xxx{FC, (xxx, xxx)(5+, 5+)} ;\\                    
        &5xxx               &Quantitatif ;\\                                    
\bottomrule                                                                     
\end{tabular}                                                                   
\caption{L'ouverture de 2SA: Réponses}                                          
\end{threeparttable}                                                            

\subsection{{Continuations après Stayman 3 Ts}}                                 
\begin{threeparttable}[t]                                                       
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}}                                                        
\toprule                                                                        
2xxx                &3xxx   &Stayman xxx{4}{+} H ;\\                            
3xxx                &       &Pas de M xxx{4} ;\\                                
3M                  &       &Une seule majeure (xxx{4} ou xxx{5}) ;\\           
3xxx                &       &Les deux M xxx{4} ;\\                              
4m\textsubscript{1} &       &(44)(14), singleton m\textsubscript{1};\\          
\bottomrule                                                                     
\end{tabular}                                                                   
\caption{2xxx: Réponses à Stayman}                                              
\end{threeparttable}                                                            

\subsection{Subsection one}                                                     

\begin{threeparttable}[t]                                                       
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}}                                                        
\toprule                                                                        
2xxx    &3xxx   &\\                                                             
3xxx    &       &\\                                                             
&3M\textsubscript{1}   &Chassé-croisé , M\textsubscript{1} xxx{4}, M\textsubscript{2} xxx{5} ; \\                                            
&3xxx                   &A jouer ;\\                                            
&4m                     &{edc}, bicolore m xxx{5}{+}, M xxx{4} ;\\              
&4M\textsubscript{1}    &M\textsubscript{1} xxx{6} belle couleur,               
M\textsubscript{2} xxx{4} ;\\                                                   
&4xxx                  &Quantitatif.\\                                          
\\                                                                              
\cmidrule(r){2-3}                                                               
2xxx    &3xxx   &\\                                                             
3xxx   &3xxx   &Chassé-croisé ;\\                                               
3xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, en attendant ;\\                               
3xxx    &       &Sans fit xxx xxx{3},  ;\\                                      
4xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, EC, contrôle xxx sans contrôle xxx ;\\         
4xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, EC, contrôles xxx, xxx sans contrôle xxx ;\\   
4xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, EC, contrôles xxx, xxx, xxx ;\\                
4xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, xxxnsedc.\\                                    
\\                                                                              
\cmidrule(r){2-3}                                                               
2xxx    &3xxx   &\\                                                             
3xxx   &3xxx   &Chassé-croisé ;\\                                               
3xxx    &       &Sans fit xxx xxx{3},  ;\\                                      
4xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, EC, contrôle xxx sans contrôle xxx ;\\         
4xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, EC, contrôles xxx, xxx sans contrôle xxx ;\\   
4xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, xxxnsedc ;\\                                   
4xxx    &       &Fit xxx xxx{3}, EC, contrôles xxx, xxx, xxx.\\                 
\bottomrule                                                                     
\end{tabular}                                                                   
\caption{2xxx: Après Stayman (réponse négative)}                                
\end{threeparttable}                                                            

\subsection{Continuations après réponse montrant au moins M 4e}                 
\begin{threeparttable}[t]                                                       
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}}                                                        
\toprule                                                                        
2xxx    &3xxx   &\\                                                             
3xxx    &       &xxx xxx{4} ou  xxx{5}, sans xxx xxx{4};\\                      
&3xxx  &EC, . Soutien xxx sans contrôle xxx ;\\                                 
&3xxx   &A jouer ;\\                                                            
&4xxx   &EC, misfit {9}{+}. Bicolore xxx xxx{5}{+}, xxx xxx{4} ;\\              
&4xxx   &EC, misfit {9}{+}. Bicolore xxx xxx{5}{+}, xxx xxx{4} ;\\              
&4xxx   &Conclusif ;\\                                                          
&4xxx   &Blackwood d'exclusion ;\\                                              
&4xxx   &RKCB xxx ;\\                                                           
&5m     &Blackwood d'exclusion xxx.\\                                           
\\                                                                              
\cmidrule(r){2-3}                                                               
2xxx    &3xxx   &\\                                                             
3xxx   &3xxx   &EC, . Soutien xxx sans contrôle xxx ;\\                         
3xxx    &       &Contrôle xxx, sans contrôle xxx ;\\                            
4xxx    &       &Contrôle xxx, xxx sans contrôle xxx ;\\                        
4xxx    &       &Contrôle xxx, xxx, Ks ;\\                                      
4xxx    &       &Sans contrôle xxx, mini, xxxnsedc ;\\                          
4xxx    &       &Fort EC, Contrôle xxx, xxx, Ks.\\                              
\\                                                                              
\cmidrule(r){2-3}                                                               
2xxx    &3xxx   &\\                                                             
3xxx   &       &xxx xxx{4} ou xxx{5}. Sans xxx xxx{4} ;\\                       
&3xxx   &A jouer ;\\                                                            
&4xxx   &EC, misfit {9}{+}. Bicolore xxx xxx{5}{+}, xxx xxx{4} ;\\              
&4xxx   &EC, misfit {9}{+}. Bicolore xxx xxx{5}{+}, xxx xxx{4} ;\\              
&4xxx   &EC, soutien xxx ;\\                                                    
&4xxx   &Conclusif ;\\                                                          
&4xxx   &RKCB xxx ;\\                                                           
&5C\textsubscript{1}    &Blackwood d'exclusion xxx.\\                           
\\                                                                              
\cmidrule(r){2-3}                                                               
2xxx    &3xxx   &\\                                                             
3xxx    &       &Les deux M xxx{4} ;\\                                          
&4xxx   &Transfert pour 4xxx. Après rectification : Passe ou contrôles ;\\      
&4xxx   &Transfert pour 4xxx. Après rectification : Passe ou contrôles ;\\      
&4M     &Naturel--Passe ou 4xxx RKCB M ;\\                                      
\\                                                                              
\cmidrule(r){2-3}                                                               
2xxx    &3xxx   &Stayman xxx{4}{+} H ;\\                                        
4xxx    &       &444(14), singleton m inconnue ;\\                              
&4xxx   &Transfert pour 4xxx. Après rectification : Passe ou contrôles ;\\      
&4xxx   &Transfert pour 4xxx. Après rectification : Passe ou contrôles ;\\      
&4M     &Naturel--Passe ou 4xxx RKCB M ;\\                                      
\bottomrule                                                                     
\end{tabular}                                                                   
\caption{2xxx: Continuations    après Stayman (réponse positive)}                                               
\end{threeparttable}                                                            
\section{Continuations après Texas majeur}        

\begin{threeparttable}[t]                                                       
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}                                                        
\toprule                                                                        
2xxx                &\hspace{-3pt}3xxx &       &Texas xxx\\                     
3xxx                & &       &Fit xxx{3} ou 2 honneurs secs ;\\                
&umn{1}{xxx}{3xxx}                  &       &xxx xxx{6} et singleton (nommé  après relais 3xxx, 4xxx étant un singleton xxx) ;\\                             
&umn{1}{xxx}{3xxx}                  &       &Régulier, pas de couleur secondaire xxx{4}.  ;\\                                                                    
&umn{1}{xxx}{4m\textsubscript{1}}   &      &Naturel, m\textsubscript{1} xxx{4}  pour jouer 6m\textsubscript{1} en 4--4, plutôt que \\                           
&umn{1}{|l}{}                                       &umn{1}{xxx}{4xxx}  &Coupe de frein ; \\                                                                   
&umn{1}{|l}{}                                      &umn{1}{xxx}{4xxx}  &Agrée   l’atout mineur ; \\                                                             
&umn{1}{|l}{}                                       &umn{1}{xxx}{4xxx}  &RKCB   xxx.\\                                                                          
&umn{1}{xxx}{4xxx}                  &      &Coupe de frein ;\\                  
\\                                                                              
3xxx                &  &       &xxx xxx{5}, xxx xxx{2} ;\\                      
\\                                                                              
 3xxx                & &       &xxx xxx{2} ;\\                                  
&umn{1}{xxx}{4xxx}                  &       &(ii) Texas xxx (4 cartes possibles);\\                                                                             
&umn{1}{xxx}{4xxx}                  &      &(i) xxx xxx{6} ;\\                  
&umn{1}{xxx}{4xxx}                  &       &(ii) Texasxxx (4 cartes possibles);\\                                                                   
&umn{1}{xxx}{4xxx}                  &      &(ii) Texas xxx (4 cartes possibles);\\                                                                             
\\                                                                              
4m\textsubscript{1} & &       &Fit xxx{4}, m\textsubscript{1} bonne couleur, idéalement 24(25) ;\\                                                           
\\                                                                              
4xxx                & &       &Fit xxx{4} et tous contrôles.\\                  
\bottomrule                                                                     
\end{tabular}                                                                   
\caption{2xxx: Réponses àTexas xxx}                                             
\end{threeparttable}                                                            
\end{document}
```

Comment: I remember seeing that question a long time ago.  It's only recently that the blank pages issue has surfaced - I'll look into removing titlesec.

Comment: **Never ignore compilation errors.** Once you get an error, the output cannot be predicted or expected. All bets are off: there may be no output or, if TeX can make some kind of sense of the input, it may manage to produce something. Your code does not compile. Hence any issues with the output being not as expected are simply irrelevant. The error should be the focus of concern. Only if you resolve that problem and compile without error is the output relevant to debugging.

Comment: Code compiles fine for me - I use lualatex. But to reproduce your issue I tried pdflatex and it doesn't compile under that! There were some overlong lines in the source and I tidied those and now my version doesn't compile under either, so it seems like a file corruption issue.  I've fixed that and put a slightly shorter version of the MWE up. It compiles under pdflatex and lualatex but still has the original blank page problem.

Comment: Jut FYI I can get those blank pages with `book` as well. Might not be `memoir` related. It seems to be always page 3. @cfr I get no compilation errors on this with either pdflatex or lualatex on TL17frozen or TL18

Comment: Thanks daleif.  My live is about 160 pages and the blanks seem to be confined to this particular section which has many full-page threeparttables.  Might it be a float issue between two consecutive ones?

Comment: Remember to use `@` when answering to someone specific, otherwise they donw know you were referring to them. There are no floats in this MWE, `threeparttable` is not a float, it is a construction to make table notes. The main issue is the `M 4e` table, it is longer than the text height and latex will rather attempt to break the page before the section rather than directly after the section. You should use floats  (and design yopur stuff so it fits on a page) or use longtables  (there is a `threeparttablex` that brings table notes to long tables.

Comment: Thanks @daleif.  I have some longtables elsewhere but I can design these ones now that I know what's happening.  If you post that answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I re-tagged your question into something more suitable. I subscribe to the `memoir` tag, which is not relevant to the true nature of this problem.

Comment: @daleif That was a good idea.

Comment: @daleif I think the code got edited to avoid compilation errors with pdfTeX. (See comments above.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here has nothing to to with the `memoir` (you get the same with `book`) class or the `titlesec` package.

The problem is

1. `threeparttable` is not a float, so you cannot use it instead of the `table` env. `threeparttable` is a construction for making table notes.
2. The table after the blank page is longer than a page (or rather a section + table is longer than the text height). Presumably LaTeX will rather break the page before the `\section` rather than breaking right after `\section` (I'm not sure about the details).

Everything comes back to normal if you remove a few lines from that table.

Recommendation: Use proper floats + design the table so it will fit on a page. Or if they are too long, switch to something similar to `longtable`